# Full screen apps (games) cause screen to turn on and off, but only if computer ran overnight

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, fullscreen

The problem:
Running any game in full screen causes the screen to turn on and off. It goes completely black for 1-2 seconds, then turns back on. This will keep happening at uneven intervals. Sometimes it will stay on for a minute or two, sometimes it will stay on for just a few seconds. Everything else continues to work while it's off - sound work, mouse and keyboard input works, etc. While the screen is on there are no visible issues - fps is steady, no video artifacts, etc.

The weird part:
This only happens if I leave the computer running overnight. A restart fixes it every time and I've never experienced the issue within the same day that I've restarted or turned it on. There are also no issues with anything that's not full screen, exiting the game stops the behavior. It also doesn't happen if playing in windowed mode.

I've checked the event log and I don't see anything being logged when this happens. This is a desktop running windows 10 with a GeForce GTX 1070 in it that's connected via display port to a single monitor. I don't have any sort of sleep settings set up where the monitor, hard drives, or any peripherals turn off after X minutes, at least everywhere I've checked.

What are some troubleshooting steps I could take to try and narrow this down?

Comment: Try a new DP cable.  Try a different connection method (DVI, HDMI, etc.)  Update your display drivers.   Check temperatures of the video adapter.  Try a different monitor.  Try that monitor on a different computer.  Try a different video adapter.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Screen occasionally flashes black](https://superuser.com/questions/496136/screen-occasionally-flashes-black), and/or [GeForce 8800 GTX: screen flashing to black](https://superuser.com/questions/1248752/geforce-8800-gtx-screen-flashing-to-black)